# Appintro gray layer in front

Tags: android

When i add Appintro into my App as its guidance. 
My app runing sucessful.but there is gray layer in front of my Fragment.
How to remove it?  My Activity like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addSlide(new Slide_First());
     addSlide(new Slide_Second());
     addSlide(new Slide_Third());
     addSlide(new Slide_Forth());
    showSkipButton(true);
    setProgressButtonEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public void onSkipPressed(Fragment currentFragment) {
    super.onSkipPressed(currentFragment);
    // Do something when users tap on Skip button.
}

@Override
public void onDonePressed(Fragment currentFragment) {
    super.onDonePressed(currentFragment);
    // Do something when users tap on Done button.
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onSlideChanged(@Nullable Fragment oldFragment, @Nullable Fragment newFragment) {
    super.onSlideChanged(oldFragment, newFragment);
    // Do something when the slide changes.
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue may simply be the way your fragments were created. Try changing the following statements:

```
 addSlide(new Slide_First());
 addSlide(new Slide_Second());
 addSlide(new Slide_Third());
 addSlide(new Slide_Forth());
```

To these:

```
    addSlide(BaseSlide.newInstance(R.layout.slide_1));
    addSlide(BaseSlide.newInstance(R.layout.slide_2));
    addSlide(BaseSlide.newInstance(R.layout.slide_3));
```

The first parameter will be used for `Fragments` and the second one will be the call to your XML layout file. In the BaseSlide.java don't forget to add [this code](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/amqtech/opensource/appintroexample/util/SampleSlide.java) provided in the library.